# Have multiple buttons (triggers) for one Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one modal that is rather large and instead of making new buttons and new modals I would prefer to just have multiple buttons that all trigger the same Modal.

Below is an example modal taken from getbootstrap.com
I have tried to create multiple buttons with the same data-target but when I click on the extra buttons no modal opens up but the background gray overlay still renders.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason my modal with multiple buttons was not rendering because the div that contained the modal was hidden inside a panel. I had to put the modal div at the top of the page so that when I click the various buttons it renders.